# Command \cs already defined in memoir class but not in amsart?

Tags: macros, memoir

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newcommand{\cs}{\Sigma}
\title{Rings and Modules}
\author{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

This fails to compile and I get the following error.

```
 ! LaTeX Error: Command \cs already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

 See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
 Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

 l.2 \newcommand{\cs}{\Sigma}
```

P.S. The code is perfectly fine with `amsart` class. Also, please tell me what is "the manual" referred to in the error message.

Comment: egreg mentions to me in the chat that: The "p. 192" refers to the LaTeX manual. -- "LaTeX, a document preparation system", by Leslie Lamport.

Comment: I would also mention, that such short cuts make the code a lot harder to understand for others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The file `memoir.cls` has this line

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cs}[1]{\texttt{\char`\\#1}}
```

which is meant to print control sequence names: `\cs{cs}` would print `\cs`. It doesn't seem a crucial command so you can use a known trick to redefine it without worries about it being defined or not:

```
\providecommand{\cs}{}
\renewcommand{\cs}{\Sigma}
```

This is safe both with the standard LaTeX classes, AMS classes and `memoir`. If you use another class, it's best to comment out the first line and see what happens. If the command is defined, try and look at its definition.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. A very enlightening answer from both you and @lockstep.

Comment: The solution here will sort, but I'd be wary of defining `\cs` other than for the reason `memoir` does. It's pretty commonly used, not just by `memoir`, so it's (almost) a 'standard' macro.

Comment: @JosephWright I guess that in a math paper one doesn't need to print control sequence names. :)

Comment: @egreg True, but in the spirit of a my LaTeX3 work I'm keen on the idea of a larger 'defined' set of commands which are  defined irrespective of document class in use. This is an area that still needs thought, of course.

Answer (score 6):

The `memoir` class indeed includes the following definition of `\cs`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cs}[1]{\texttt{\char`\\#1}}
```

It is used to format in-text-examples of control sequences.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
%\newcommand{\cs}{\Sigma}
\title{Rings and Modules}
\author{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\cs{mycommand}
\end{document}
```

[image]